# error in installing internet explorer using ies4linux on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, wine, gtk, ie

I'm trying to install internet explorer using ies4linux based on official document. 
after extracting ies4linux and run it 
I face a gui which I can select a version of internet explorer but after pressing ok I get the following error :

```
 Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.24.27/gtk/gtktextview.c:3571:gtk_text_view_validate_onscreen: assertion failed: (text_view->onscreen_validated)

ui/pygtk/python-gtk.sh: line 6: 12968 Aborted                 (core dumped) python "$IES4LINUX"/ui/pygtk/ies4linux-gtk.py
```

could any one help me on this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried playonlinux and it installed ie8 for me.